# Delete duplicate value when the duplicate values are not in the same column for multiple ids in sql

Tags: sql, excel, duplicates

my data is consists of  many customer id with column a and column b. Can somebody suggest me how to remove duplicated in such time where the combinations of the two columns are interchanged form of the columns

Below is the snippet of my data

```
Customer_Id Col_1 Col_2

1215682 A   B

1215682 B   A
```

The combination above formed are AB & BA , how can we remove such duplicates
Similar to this customer id there are many other customer id.

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: Is it a database or an Excel file? Why did you tag it with excel and sql?

Comment: General hint: get the pairs: ID + sorted string, which is concatenation of two columns. Then just remove duplicates.

Comment: The fact you have two columns that could carry the same data is indicative of poor [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). My first suggestion would be to reevaluate the design of this table, this is likely the primary reason you are getting this issue.